# How can I find out the value of the keys in a dictionary object?

Tags: c#

I have this API call:

```
HttpResponse<string> response = 
    Unirest.get("https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/" + word.Name)
    .header("X-Mashape-Key", "xxxx")
    .header("Accept", "application/json")
    .asJson<string>();
```

Here is the class for the `HttpResponse`:

```
public class HttpResponse<T>
{
    public HttpResponse(HttpResponseMessage response);

    public T Body { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Headers { get; }
    public Stream Raw { get; }
}
```

I have no problem getting the Body (`response.Body`) or the Code but what I would like to do is to get this header:

```
[7] = {[X-RateLimit-requests-Remaining, 2498]}
```

Can someone tell me how I could check the response returned and find out the value of the `X-RateLimit-requests-Remaining`?

Comment: How about: `response.Headers["X-RateLimit-requests-Remaining"]` ? So you know how dictionaries work yeah?

Comment: What is this `Unirest` and why are its methods not following .NET naming conventions?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen It's a [lightweight HTTP request library](http://unirest.io/net.html) and the naming is probably due to compatibility reasons with other supported languages.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer: That's just a bizarre. And the other languages seem to be following their respective conventions.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Yeah, it is a bit weird seeing C# methods in camel case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionaries have something called an [**indexer**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx). The datatype of your indexer is the datatype of your `Key` ([`Dictionary<Key,Value>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Indexers are similar to property getters and setters and are implemented like this:

```
public TValue this[TKey index]
{
    // this will return when being called e.g. 'var x = dictionary[key];' 
    get { return whatever; }

    // and here 'value' is whatever you pass to the setter e.g. 'dictionary[kex] = x;'
    set { whatever = value; }
}
```

In you case that would be:

```
// "Key" is just an example, use "X-RateLimit-requests-Remaining" instead ;)
response.Headers["Key"];
```